# How can I get innerHTML when clicking a button in React js?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm trying to use [material-ui-flat-pagination](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-flat-pagination). Since the library seems not to provide page number when clicking previous or next button, I'm trying to get the value by myself. It provides only one `onClick` prop, so I used `event.target` to get the value that I click.

[image]

`event.target` shows the above tag, and I need the value `3` inside the span tag. How can I get the value in React js? Am I approaching the right way to get the page number with the library [material-ui-flat-pagination](https://www.npmjs.com/package/material-ui-flat-pagination)?

Comment: uhh yes it does... it's right in the docs.. `offset`...`onClick={(e, offset) => this.handleClick(offset)}`

Comment: That's where I used `event.target`

Comment: why bother... you want the page number, that's what `offset` . `pageNum === offset + 1`

Comment: but it says offset is how many rows I skip, so I thought I could get the page number by doing `offset / limit + 1`, it's working when I click the next button, however if I randomly change the page number, it doesn't properly give me the page number. Can I not directly get the innerHTML value in Reactjs?

Comment: @azium, your logic only works when the page shows only one row.

Comment: you're saying page..... do you mean page like `1-10` is page 1 and `11 - 20` is page 2?

Comment: ohhhhh sorry I see what you mean.. one sec

Comment: are you sure `offset / limit + 1` doesn't work? seems to be working for me https://codesandbox.io/s/kkl68vp9xo

Comment: and as a general note.. you should **NEVER** be accessing the dom directly in a react application... like never ever. if you have to do this, something has gone horribly wrong

Comment: @azium, I do not really agree about "Never ever accessing DOM" in react. In my oppinion "Never manipulate DOM" will be more appropriate. Rarely we need to access DOM in react ( not to mention it will be related to this question ). For reference, please check: https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html or https://reactjs.org/docs/integrating-with-other-libraries.html

Comment: @Bayu yeah okay, i mean even sometimes you need to manipulate the dom. it's just that it's such a rare need that every other option must have already been exhausted

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I am sorry for not adding a comment i don't have the reputation yet.
x will note you the number you are asking but don't try to update offset with x cause of the offset calculation defined on core.ts of the module.

`export const getOffset = (page: number, limit: number): number => {
  const offset = (page - 1) * limit;
  return offset < 0 ? 0 : offset;
};`

Although you can try to get the HTML you want by parsing the event. a trick is to match a case with the params that the interface provide like next or previous labels

```
e.target.innerText
e.currentTarget.childNodes[0].innerText
```

*mind it is a string so care your number comparisons

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import CssBaseline from "@material-ui/core/CssBaseline";
import { createMuiTheme, MuiThemeProvider } from "@material-ui/core/styles";
import Pagination from "material-ui-flat-pagination";

const theme = createMuiTheme();

class Example extends React.Component {
constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = { offset: 0, limit: 3, total: 132, calc: 1, nlabel: ">>", plabel: "<<" };
}

handleClick(e, offset) {
    let y = e.target.innerText; 
    //let y =e.currentTarget.childNodes[0].innerText;

    if (y === this.state.plabel) y = Number(this.state.calc) - 1;
    if (y === this.state.nlabel) y = Number(this.state.calc) + 1;
    let x = offset / this.state.limit + 1;
    console.log("x:" + x + " - y:" + y);
    this.setState({ offset, calc: y });
}

render() {
    return (
        <MuiThemeProvider theme={theme}>
            <div>{this.state.offset}</div>
            <div>{this.state.calc}</div>
            <CssBaseline />
            <Pagination
                limit={this.state.limit}
                offset={this.state.offset}
                total={this.state.total}
                onClick={(e, offset) => this.handleClick(e, offset)}
                nextPageLabel={this.state.nlabel}
                previousPageLabel={this.state.plabel}
            />
        </MuiThemeProvider>
    );
}
}

ReactDOM.render(<Example />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: Thank you! exactly what I was looking for! By the way, I just want to make sure if this is the best way to get the page number in the library. I was trying to have this way cuz I thought the library doesn't seem to provide page number explicitly. Doesn't it?

Comment: Directly no but i am a junior in react. It seems that the core creates an interface of page objects and casts them by interpolation to the component element. Is there a way in react to access children **state** by catching an event on element?